# Monotouch how to retrieve objectAtIndex from NSArray in C#

Tags: c#, nsarray

In objectiveC given an NSArray fred containing strings I can say:

```
NSString *s = [fred ObjectAtIndex:5];
```

What is the c# equivalent?  Rosetta stone says to use the method `ValueAt` but that returns an `IntPtr`.

```
var i = fred.ValueAt(5);
```

But then you are left with how to convert an `IntPtr` to `NSString` pointer.

Answer (score 6):

Going via IntPtr feels like a bad idea. Instead, as long as you know the type of the item you want to get, you can just use the following:

```
int index = 0;
NSString str = myNsArr.GetItem<NSString>(index);
```

Answer (score 5):

I've came to the same situation.
You can convert that IntPtr to an NSString with new NSString(), like:

```
string strValue = new NSString(nsArr.ValueAt(1));
```

It's probably too late for you, but maybe it will help other people.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I get the error "'Foundation.NSNumber.NSNumber(System.IntPtr)' is inaccessible due to it's protection level". 

Upon checking the Xamarin's bindings for NSNumber, I can see that it is protected: protected internal NSNumber (IntPtr handle);

Answer (score 1):

```
string strValue = NSString.FromHandle(nsArr.ValueAt(1));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explain how it works, and describe when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.